# R plot density smoothed time series

Tags: r, graph, charts, probability

I wish to make a probability distribution of some time series data. My data is in the following format

```
00:00, 3
01:00, 50
05:00, 13
10:00, 34
17:00, 80
21:00, 100
```

The time column has some missing values that R will have to interpolate. I want to get a nice smooth curve to highlight the busy periods. I have tried with `ts`, `density` and `plot` but these don't produce what I'm after. For example,

```
data1 <- read.csv(file="c:\\abc\\ts.csv", head=FALSE, sep=",")
data1$V1 <- strptime(data1$V1, format="%H:%M")
plot(data1$V2, density(data1$V1), type="l")
```

But this gives me lines drawn in crazy order and as a probability distribution.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are definitely after package [zoo](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/zoo/index.html), which has several functions to deal with NAs. See `na.aggregate`, `na.approx` and `na.locf` also.

Comment: What does NA stand for? Having trouble finding it on the web, my search terms suck: r, zoo, na

Comment: @Jason Axelson: NA = missing value (not available)

Answer (score 2):

You made it a little harder than you might realize.   I'll make it easier for now by adding a date in front of your times.

Also, I added a variable "texinp" and a textConnection() statement so you can cut/paste the following code and run it directly.   The data is loaded into variable texinp and is read by the read.zoo statement in a similar way to reading a .csv file.    For now, this will allow you to plot things and gives you an idea of how to read .csv files using read.zoo.

```
library(zoo)
library(chron)

texinp <- "
Time,  Mydata
2011-02-06 00:00, 3
2011-02-06 01:00, 50
2011-02-06 05:00, 13
2011-02-06 10:00, 34
2011-02-06 17:00, 80
2011-02-06 21:00, 100"

myd.zoo <- read.zoo(textConnection(texinp), header=TRUE, FUN = as.chron, sep=",")
myd.zoo

plot(myd.zoo)
```

From your question, you talked about "busy periods".   I may be wrong, but I'm assuming that the value of 100 at time 21:00 is the "busiest period".   If that's true, then you don't need a density plot, and the above plot is what you're after.

Let me know if I'm wrong.